# 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written the following code but for some reasons the `.get()` gives me nothing.

I have tried printing `fullname.get()`'s `len` and it gives me `0` with following error:

```
 <class 'str'>
0

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[Finished in 21.5s]
```

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from db import DBConnect
from listComp import ListComp

conn = DBConnect()



def Complaint():
        comp = Tk()
        comp.geometry('1366x768')
        comp.title('Complaint Box')
        comp.configure(background='#2919bf')
        #Style
        style1 = Style()
        style1.theme_use('classic')
        for elem in ['TLabel', 'TButton', 'TRadioutton']:
            style1.configure(elem, background='#35a5e1')

        labels = ['Full Name:', 'Gender:','Choose a Category', 'Comment:']
        for i in range(4):
            Label(comp, text=labels[i]).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=200, pady=25)
        BuList = Button(comp, text='List Comp.')
        BuList.grid(row=5, column=1)
        BuSubmit = Button(comp, text='Submit Now')
        BuSubmit.grid(row=5, column=2)
        tkvar = StringVar(comp)
        # Dictionary with options
        choices = { 'Student','Teacher','Management','Infrastructure',''}
        tkvar.set('') # set the default option
        #Gridx1353
        popupMenu = OptionMenu(comp, tkvar, *choices)
        popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)
        tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown(tkvar.get()))
        #Entries
        fullname = Entry(comp, width=40, font=('Arial', 14))
        fullname.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
        SpanGender = StringVar()
        r1 = Radiobutton(comp, text='Male', value='male', variable=SpanGender).grid(row=1, column=1)
        r2 =  Radiobutton(comp, text='Female', value='female', variable=SpanGender).grid(row=1, column=2)
        comment = Text(comp, width=35, height=5, font=('Arial', 14))
        comment.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        f=fullname.get()
        print(type(f))
        print(len(f))
        print(fullname.get())
        s=SpanGender.get()
        t=tkvar.get()
        c=comment.get(1.0,'end')
        BuSubmit.config(command=lambda:SaveData(f,s,t,c))
        BuList.config(command=ShowList)
        comp.mainloop()
# on change dropdown value
def change_dropdown(tkvar):
    print( tkvar )

# link function to change dropdown

def SaveData(fullname,SpanGender,tkvar,comment):
    msg1= "Failed please fill all information!."
    #print(len(fullname))
    if len(fullname) == 0 or len(SpanGender)==0:
        showinfo(title='Add Info',message=msg1)
    else:
        msg = conn.Add(fullname,SpanGender,tkvar,comment)
        #fullname.delete(0, 'end')
        #comment.delete(1.0, 'end')
        #r1.deselect()
        #r2.deselect()
        showinfo(title='Add Info', message=msg)

def ShowList():
    listrequest = ListComp()





#Config
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1366x768')
root.title('Complaint Box')
root.configure(background='#2919bf')
style = Style()
style.theme_use('classic')
for elem in ['TLabel', 'TButton']:
    style.configure(elem, background='#35a5e1')
Label(root, text="Welcome To Indian Government Complaint Department",font="Verdana 24 bold").grid(row=1, column=0,padx=150,pady=10)
BuRegister = Button(root, text='Register Complaint',command=Complaint)
BuRegister.grid(row=5,pady=200,padx=10)
#BuRegister.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
BuView = Button(root, text='View Complaint',command=ShowList)
BuView.grid(row=7,pady=0,padx=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're calling `fullname.get()` about a millisecond after creating the widget. The user won't have had time to enter anything. That wouldn't cause the "NoneType is not callable" error, but it's definitely a problem.

Comment: I don't see where it is, but you're probably calling a function in a place where you should just be passing the function as a callback.

Comment: There is a large amount of problems here. You call `Tk()` more than once, You import tkinter and tkinter.ttk as *, you assign a value to a local function variable that is basically deleted after the function is complete. And some other issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: you should add Button which user click after it put text in Entry and this buttons should run function which get value from entry. Currently you try to get value directly after you create Entry in memory - even before `mainloop()` displays window with this Entry. `mianloop()` start programs and display window - so everythink before `mainloop()` is executed before you even see window.

Comment: @furas that button exist they just use `get()` earlier than they should be.

Comment: @Mike and this is what I tried to said in my comment. They use it in wrong moment and Button which runs function which gets this value can be solution.

Comment: @furas well you said "you should add Button " but the button was already. I was just letting you know they already had the button.

Comment: I wrote something more: `add Button ... and this buttons should run function which get value from entry` :)  I saw buttons but they didn't runs any function and I didn't try to guess if existing buttons are created to get value or not. Frankly, It doesn't matter if buttons exist or not - more important is `"and this button should run function which get value from entry"` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for me to reproduce your error. I suspect it could be caused by `import *` or one of your bad `get()` methods. Likely the `get()` methods as you do not even set value of entry's text and probably getting the `Null` value from that.

Keep in mind you need to run the `get()` method inside of a function and not in the same location you are initializing your code.

One of the other major problems is the use of `Tk()` more than once. You always want to use only one instance of `Tk()` when building a Tkinter GUI. For new windows use `Toplevel()`.

I have cleaned up your code to follow PEP8 more closely. Let me know if this helps.

```
import tkinter as tk  # use these imports so you do not overwrite other imports.
import tkinter.ttk as ttk  # use these imports so you do not overwrite other imports.
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox  # avoid import *. Its normally not needed.
from db import DBConnect
from listComp import ListComp


def complaint(master):
        comp = tk.Toplevel(master)
        comp.geometry('1366x768')
        comp.title('Complaint Box')
        comp.configure(background='#2919bf')
        style1 = ttk.Style()
        style1.theme_use('classic')
        tkvar = tk.StringVar(master)
        tkvar.set('')
        labels = ['Full Name:', 'Gender:', 'Choose a Category', 'Comment:']
        choices = {'Student', 'Teacher', 'Management', 'Infrastructure', ''}

        for elem in ['TLabel', 'TButton', 'TRadiobutton']:  # fixed typo
            style1.configure(elem, background='#35a5e1')

        for i in range(4):
            ttk.Label(comp, text=labels[i]).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=200, pady=25)

        popup_menu = tk.OptionMenu(comp, tkvar, *choices)
        popup_menu.grid(row=2, column=1)
        tkvar.trace('w', lambda: change_dropdown(tkvar))  # corrected your trace command.
        fullname = tk.Entry(comp, text='', width=40, font=('Arial', 14))
        fullname.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
        span_gender = tk.StringVar(master)
        ttk.Radiobutton(comp, text='Male', value='male', variable=span_gender).grid(row=1, column=1)
        ttk.Radiobutton(comp, text='Female', value='female', variable=span_gender).grid(row=1, column=2)
        comment = tk.Text(comp, width=35, height=5, font=('Arial', 14))
        comment.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        ttk.Button(comp, text='List Comp.', command=show_list).grid(row=5, column=1)
        ttk.Button(comp, text='Submit Now', command=lambda: save_data(fullname, span_gender,
                                                                      tkvar, comment)).grid(row=5, column=2)


def change_dropdown(tkvar):
    print(tkvar.get())


def save_data(fullname, span_gender, tkvar, comment):
    msg1 = "Failed please fill all information!."
    if len(fullname.get()) == 0 or len(span_gender.get()) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Add Info', message=msg1)
    else:
        conn = DBConnect()  # moved conn to the function. No point in opening connection until its needed.
        msg = conn.Add(fullname.get(), span_gender.get(), tkvar.get(), comment.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Add Info', message=msg)
        # you should probably close the connection here.


def show_list():
    # cannot test this function as I do not know what `ListComp()` is doing.
    # That said this function is currently pointless as the local variable
    # will be basically deleted when the function finishes.
    listrequest = ListComp()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1366x768')
root.title('Complaint Box')
root.configure(background='#2919bf')
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('classic')

for elem in ['TLabel', 'TButton']:
    style.configure(elem, background='#35a5e1')

ttk.Label(root, text="Welcome To Indian Government Complaint Department",
          font="Verdana 24 bold").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=150, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='Register Complaint', command=lambda: complaint(root)).grid(row=5, pady=200, padx=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='View Complaint', command=show_list).grid(row=7, pady=0, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how do i load next frame on the parent frame in above code

Comment: @adityagupta that is a question for a separate post. My goal was to solve the issue in this question. If you cannot work it out on your own you should post a new question.